# Notepad++ moving letters from the end of text to the begining

Tags: numbers, notepad++, move, swap, letter

i have a text file with values that start a few digits and end with a letter or two at maximum.
i need to move those letters to the front.

Original data looks like this:
56465A
498558DF
90255C

and need them to become like:
A56465
DF498558
C90255

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try capturing the leading numbers and trailing uppercase letters in a word, in two separate capture groups.  Then, replace with the numbers and letters swapped.

```
Find:    \b(\d+)([A-Z]+)\b
Replace: $2$1
```

**Edit:**

If the group of letters could appear anywhere in the string, then we can use a slightly more complex pattern:

```
Find:    \b(\d*)([A-Z]+)(\d*)\b
Replace: $2$1$3
```

Comment: but there was a few chunks where i missed it up by putting the letter in the middle of the string like this:  498DF558    how can i fix it like the rest?

Comment: @Shadi You are changing your question after others have already answered, and that's rude.  In any case, I updated my answer to cover your new data.

Comment: It happens :-) ... just take it as feedback for your future questions.

Comment: i didn't mean to change the question, it was an additional issue that was found after i applied you initial great solution.. and you came up with even greater one!! i can't thank you enough Sir!